# What is the meaning of the word "lexia"?

Tags: meaning

> "Thus, Landow (1992) argues that fully fledged hypertext systems afford readers the opportunity to write against the initial text, participating in the production of meaning by creating notes or linked lexia that may support or contradict the initial author's." - (Spinello, R., & Tavani, H. (2005), Intellectual Property Rights in a Networked World: Theory and Practice)

I couldn't find good search results for this term. It has been used in a couple of places in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ["An Introduction" of the third edition (2006) of the referenced work by Landow](https://books.google.com/books?id=qqdomnPTL9cC&pg=PA208&dq=lexia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCpMSexNjKAhUN0WMKHS_BCe4Q6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=lexia%20barthes&f=false) (see pp. 2-3), this explanation of his use of the term is given:

[image: lexia3-1]
[image: lexia3-2]

Thus Landow is using 'lexia' to signify "blocks of text", after Barthes' term, and is defining 'hypertext' using that term plus "the electronic links that join them".

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexie) claims that 'lexia' in this sense originated with Barthes:

> **lexie** ‎(*plural* lexies)
>    1. (literary theory) A minimal unit of reading, such as a sentence or sentence fragment.

The claim is supported with this quote from the introduction to Calloud's [*Structural Analysis of Narrative*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mRxtAAAAIAAJ&dq=Structural%20analysis%20of%20narrative&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=lexie) (p. 15), which Barthes wrote:

> It is essential for the analyst to be able to construct these canonic statements out of the linguistic statements given in the lexies.

Without checking *Structural Analysis of Narrative* I can't be sure that the use of 'lexia' with the meaning "a minimal unit of reading" originated with Barthes.

In any case, Barthes' use (translated as 'lexia' from the French *lexie*) was more nuanced. As explained by Mireille Ribière in [*Barthes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9nxY_xg9DxgC&pg=PA42&dq=Structural%20analysis%20of%20narrative&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUnraZz9jKAhVB4mMKHTZXBVwQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=lexia&f=false) (2008),

[image]

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be used as a singular noun in the quote you give and a plural noun in the quote in the question.

Comment: Barthes seems to have actually used the term *lexie,* in French. Not sure if that makes it more understandable: http://fagerjord.no/blog/archive/hypertex/nodesnot.html I'm somewhat incharitably inclined to think "lexia" is just dog-Latin, but perhaps there's some principle to its construction. Maybe I can ask on the Latin SE; it only needs a few more commits to enter private beta.

Comment: I found one source at least that uses the plural *lexias* (once, in the middle of the page, among several cases of plural *lexia.* Possibly a copyediting error?): https://books.google.com/books?id=AUrXCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=lexia+hypertext+Barthes&source=bl&ots=P8HVFVKTiM&sig=ddBzQPksFRhm0pnuY5nY8S-M4ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizr5Tqx9jKAhVJ-2MKHaOGB-YQ6AEILTAG#v=onepage&q=lexia%20hypertext%20Barthes&f=false (a little further I came across the interesting words *scripton* and *texton*...)

Comment: It seems to be related to linguistics; the same root as *lexical.* http://encyclopedie_universelle.fracademic.com/52206/lexie

Comment: @sumelic Wiktionary claims *lexie* originated from Barthes: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexie with the meaning "A minimal unit of reading, such as a sentence or sentence fragment"